# How to save lists that have been changed during execution?

Tags: python, list, save

So, Im making a text based Rpg (very similar to Progress Quest). The only lists worth saving are the weapons and items lists as well as your name and class. At the beginning of the game, you get those two lists emptied and your name reset to 0.

`weapons = []` That is how it starts.

`weapons = ["sword", "bow", "staff"]` That is how it ends.

I want a way to be able to start the same or a copy of the program with those elements saved. How do I do that? The following is the entire script... and please note, I'm making this just for fun and so i know ways to make it better and bigger; please, just comment on the topic im posting about.

```
import time
import random

allThings = ["gold coin", "Silver Coin", "Copper Coin", "Twinkies",
             "Human Tissue", "Stuffed Bear", "Hulk Toy", "Pen", "Bobblehead",
             "Charger", "Lenovo Thinkpad Modle T420",
             "Stephen King Book: Full Dark, No Stars", "Toy Laser Gun",
             "Car Keys", "Alarm Clock", "Casio Watch", "Python Manual",
             "Tissues", "Screws", "Spare CDs", "USB Flash Drive", "Spoon",
             "Fork", "Kitchen Knife", "BasketBall", "Paper Bag",
             "Crubled Paper", "Water Bottle", "Technical Document",
             "Plastic Glove", "Toy Bus", "Gas Canister", "Bracelet",
             "Space Suit", "Nuclear Bomb", "Test Tubes", "Light Bulb",
             "Mirror", "Gun Powder", "Arrow", "Human Brain", "Human Heart",
             "Human Kidney", "Human Lung", "Human Stomach"]
Enemies = ["a Corrupted Police Officer", "A Half-Lizard", "A Dog",
           "A Failed Surgery Client"]
inv = []
Equip = []
EquipAll = ["Sharp Stick", "Sharp Metal Scrap", "Pin", "Pencil", "Raw Thick
            Stick", "Moddified Stick", "Grandpa's Axe", "Cursed Axe", "Fine
            Blade", "Wooden Sword", "BB Gun", "Nerf Gun", "Human Arm", "22.
            Caliber Pistol", "45. Caliber Pistol", "Colt 45.", "9mm Pistol",
            "Ice Staff", "Fire Staff", "5.66mm Bullpup Rifle", "7.22 Assault
            Rifle", "357. Magnum", "44. Magnum", "FAL Rifle", "7.62mm Rifle",
            "308. Rifle", "Laser Kilo Gun", "Laser Mega Gun",
            "Laser Deca Gun", "Laser Hecto Gun", "Laser Giga Gun",
            "Laser Tera Gun", "Laser Peta Gun", "Laser Exa Gun",
            "Laser Zeta Gun", "Laser Yotta Gun", "Inferno Blade",
            "Blade of the Red Dragon", "Frag Granade", "Spear", "Shotgun",
            "308. Sniper Rifle", "Bow", "Attack Dog", "Rolling Pin"]
chance = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
debt = 1000000
name = 0

c = 0
x = 0
y = 0

def Start():
    global debt
    if len(inv)<10:
        x = random.choice(allThings)
        print "*********************************************************************"
        print("You came across and executed " + random.choice(Enemies) + " ...")
        time.sleep(5)
        print "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
        print("You found " + x + " ...")
        inv.append(x)
        c = random.choice(chance)
        if c == ("1"):
            print "----------------------------------------------------------------"
            y = random.choice(EquipAll)
            print("You found " + y + " as a weapon...")
            Equip.append(y)
            print "****************************************************************"
        print "\n"
        print "////////////////////////////////////////"
        print("Name: " + name + "  Race: " + race)
        print"____________________________"
        print("Debt due: " + str(debt))
        print"____________________________"
        print "Items: \n"
        print inv
        print "___________________________"
        print "Weapons: \n"
        print Equip
        print "////////////////////////////////////////"
        time.sleep(7)
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        Start()
    elif len(inv)>9:
        print "+++++++++++++++++++++++"
        print "+Going to pawn shop...+"
        print "+++++++++++++++++++++++"
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Selling " + str(inv) + " ...")
        inv[:] = []
        time.sleep(13)
        print "\n"
        print "Items sold. You got $10"
        debt = debt - 10
        time.sleep(5)
        print "Heading back to the world"
        time.sleep(10)
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        print "\n"
        Start()

print "-------------------THE 2017 Executioner------------------------"
print"Select your name:"
name = raw_input()
print "\n"
print "Select your race: Half-Lizard, Octopus, etc (You can even make one up):"
race = raw_input()
print "\n"
print "One last thing... are you a man or a woman?"
sex = raw_input()
print "\n"
print "******************************************************************************"
print "****************************Your Story Begins Here****************************"
print "******************************************************************************"
print "\n"
print "\n"
print "Underground Medical Files:"
print "\n"
print("Our latest client, " + name + ", has suffered a terrible accident..."
      + name + " was brought here by some friends... We set up a 'full body "
      "surgery' for this " + sex + " ..." + name + " decided to become a "
      + race + ".... this is the most expensive surgery we have ever done"
      "... We thought " + name + " would be able to pay for it... But after "
      "we said that they were in debt.... well, the client went full-on "
      "beserk .... Now this " + race + " is going around the world doing "
      "who-knows-what...." + "\n" + " Signed, /\\@..... Director of the "
      "illegal underground Hospital and Surgeries")
xcv = raw_input("Press Enter to Begin...")
print "\n"
print "\n"
print "Loading..."
time.sleep(30)
print "\n"

Start()
```

Comment: Write your list to a file, and when script runs, load the file again.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way to do this in Python is with the `pickle` module. For Python 3 the [documentation is here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html). An example from this documentation:

```
import pickle

# An arbitrary collection of objects supported by pickle.
data = {
    'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
    'b': ("character string", b"byte string"),
    'c': {None, True, False}
}

with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    # Pickle the 'data' dictionary using the highest protocol available.
    pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

This example saves a nested data structure (a dict with some lists, sets and tuples in it) into a file named `data.pickle`. Here's how it can be loaded back:

```
import pickle

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    # The protocol version used is detected automatically, so we do not
    # have to specify it.
    data = pickle.load(f)
```